# Extract certain text of a string using mysql

Tags: mysql, url, string-parsing, url-parsing

I have the following string:

```
https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/26056120_2094108927485604_7093424189760207868_n.png
```

What I want is to keep only:

```
26056120_2094108927485604_7093424189760207868_n.png
```

I already tried using LOCATE and INSTR, but without any success. Some people told me to use regex, but I don't know how to do it in MySQL.

All I need is info about the correct path to do this.

PS: 
1 - I need to UPDATE
2 - REPLACE isnt an option, I have another facebook strings that are different.

Thanks.

Comment: So the first part is always exactly this, `https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/`? Then you will only need a basic SUBSTRING call, because the length of the part you want to remove is already known to you ...

Comment: Please edit the question to provide proper specs (is the string always `https://scontent-sjc3-1.../68_n.png`? can't it ever be e.g. `https://scontent-sjc3-1.../69_n.png`?) and show your attempts. This is not a free code writing service ;-)

Comment: We don't change the titles of questions when they are satisfactorily answered. The point of SO is to create a treasure trove of questions for other programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want, it seems, everything after the last `/` in each  URL string.  This is a job [for `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` with a negative last parameter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_column, '/', -1)
```

will do the trick.

When I was six monhths into learning MySQL, I found it very helpful to take two hours to reread these two manual pages.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I adapted this and worked like a charm. Thanks for sharing this content, it will be very useful to me

Answer (score 0):

### You can try something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_content, LEFT(post_content, LENGTH(post_content) - 36) as gallery_content_post, 
    post_title, substring(post_content,12, 1) as gallery_id
    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE id=[some id]
```

Hope this will work